# Component input parameter is received as "undefined" but a value has been specified

Tags: angular, undefined

I have the following `TableMultipleEditComponent` in my Angular application:

```
export class TableMultipleEditComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() emitMultipleClose: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<
    boolean
    >();
    @Output() emitHoverAndData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    showBar: boolean;
    @Input()
    table: Table;
    @Input()
    checkedRows;
    @Input()
    recordId: string ;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(">> rId-oninit" , this.recordId) ;
        .....
    }
}
```

And in the html I am passing the `[recordId]` input value as `_INSERT_`:

```
<app-table-multiple-edit
     [table]="table"
     [checkedRows]="checkedRows"
     [recordId]="_INSERT_"
     (emitMultipleClose)="closeSingleRowInsert($event)"
     (emitHoverAndData)="showMultipleEditStatus($event)">
</app-table-multiple-edit>
```

When I run this in the console I always get `>> rId-oninit undefined`

I have tried using other values like "-1" and cleaning the cache, as you probably guess that means I am running out of options.

What am I doing wrong ? what can be changing the value between my html and the `ngOnInit` method

Comment: Try removing the [ ] from `[recordId]="_INSERT_"`. Angular is treating "\_INSERT\_" as an expression and trying to evaluate it - hence undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular, when you use `[input]="data"` in your HTML, `data` is basically a template expression. Template expressions are similar to JavaScript.

Angular executes the `data` and assigns it to a property of a binding target, here `input`. This allows us to dynamically change the value assigned to the `input` from the component by changing `data`.

This is similar to interpolation in AngularJS, where in order to display `{{data}}` in your HTML, `data` needs to be defined in your controller.

In your case, `[recordId]="_INSERT_"`, recordId is the `Input()` binding target and `_INSERT_` is your template expression. Angular tries to execute this expression but since you have not defined `_INSERT_` in your component, it evaluates to `undefined`.

If you require to pass a constant string to your `@Input()`, simply pass a string as the expression like so `[recordId]="'This is just an example'"`. If you require it to be dynamic, you should assign a value to `_INSERT_` in your component.

Since the template expression is similar to JavaScript, you may even pass a conditional expression if required, `[recordId]="recordExists ? '1' : null"`

Hope this answers your question.

For more info, here's a reference to the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions